# How to kill java process on windows according it's parameters

Tags: java, windows, parameters, process, kill

I would like to kill a process using java  on windows by it's parameters.
If I have an exe and I run it using "exe param1 param2 etc.." and let's say param1 is unique but exe is not, I woulk like to kill the process by param1.

How can I do that ?

Comment: How did you start the process?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you mean.

If you want to kill the process in Windows by command in Java you need to type this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /F <processname>.exe")
```

It executes the Windows command passed as the string of the method of Runtime class.

**taskkill** - command ends one or more tasks or processes. 
**/F** - parameter specifies process to be terminated

Comment: No good. I have several processes with the same instance, but the parameters are different

Comment: Please provide an explanation with your code, so the OP can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use following command to find the java process id then use taskkill to kill the process or use [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) in windows and use linux command to kill the process hth

```
jps -lv | findstr "STRING"
```

You could use following command to find the tasklist with commandline column

```
wmic path win32_process get  | findstr java.exe
```

Comment: Where do I get jps ?

Comment: In jdk/bin directory, jps, Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool. Look like this does not provide program parameter info. so you have to use tasklist or wmic to get the commandline the need to filter by parameter. hth

Answer (score -1):

target process started via command line : notepad killme.txt"

for /f "tokens=1,2" %i in ('wmic path win32_process get Commandline') do (IF "%j" == "killme.txt" (taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq %i*"))